# Ordered sequential text matching

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-matching, string-matching

I want to match the strings and get a score in the following manner,

```
   string 1: 4556677, string 2: 2556677, score: 0
   string 1: 123345873009, string 2: 123345873112, score: 9
   string 1: 22334567, string 2: 22334500, score: 6
```

So the score represents **common first n digits**, from left to right.

I have a list of 100K string 1 and 30M string 2, I would like to filter down all the pairs (string 1 and 2) with a score greater than 'x'.

Is there an algorithm available to do this task instead of brutal force sequential matching? I have tables stored in apache hive/hbase and would like to implement the approach either in spark or java mapreduce. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I conclude that your "score" represents the leftmost character position at which the strings differed.

Never mind "mapreduce," plain-Jane Java can do this very easily.

**

> public int  score( String  string1, String  string2 ) {
>       char  sbuf1[] = string1.toCharArray();
>       char  sbuf2[] = string2.toCharArray();
>
> int  complen = sbuf1.length;
>
> if( sbuf2.length < complen ) {
>           complen = sbuf2.length;
>         }
>       for(
>   int  i = 0; i < complen; i++ ) {
>           if( sbuf1[ i ] !=
>   sbuf2[ i ] ) {
>               return
>   i;
>            }
>       }
>    return -1;  //
>   indicates no mismatch detected before one string exhausted
>   }

**

Comment: Appreciate your taking time on this. But this one is brute force one-to-one comparison, this would make the number of pairs to be checked as '100k*30M' which is not efficient, even considering eliminating the pairs that don't share same first digit. I need to know if there is any data structure(tree like) that can accommodate a fast implementation of this matching.